# Symfony 2 Dependency Injection: is it possible to get a service by class name?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Traditionally, you would use the service container this way:

```php
$container->get('my_service');
```

However, provided that only one definition of a specific class exists, I'd like to get this service by class name:

```php
$container->xxx('My\Application\Service');
```

Is this possible with the [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible since Symfony 3.3:

For example if you have a UserManager like this:

```
services:
# ...
# traditional service definition
app.manager.user:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\UserManager
    tags:  ['kernel.event_subscriber']
```

then you can get it in the following ways:

```
// before Symfony 3.3
$this->get('app.manager.user')->save($user);

// Symfony 3.3+
$this->get(UserManager::class)->save($user);
```

[source](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-optional-class-for-named-services)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible, because:

- a class can (and in many cases will) appear more than once [1]
- the main reason to use a DIC is to decouple a concrete implementation
  from its usage and therefore you don't need a DIC at all, if you want
  an instance of a concrete class.

[1] Saying, that this one class appears only once is no good argument to implement an edge case into the DIC itself.

Comment: I got your point. My idea was to use that as a foundation to an autowiring system, where we could inject dependencies into a class just by looking at its definition. But you're right, especially when using interfaces, that makes no sense in the way asked in the question.